# How to append <br> to the div tag using append statement?

Tags: jquery

```
var details=[{
                "Name":"Bhavani",
                "PhoneNo":["123456","123456"],
                "Email Id":["mamata@gmail.com","mamata@yahoo.com"],
                "Birthday":"21/16/22/33"
            },
            {
                "Name":"Mamata",
                "PhoneNo":["123456","123456"],
                "Email Id":["mamata@gmail.com","mamata@yahoo.com"],
                "Birthday":"21/16/22/33"
            }
        ];   
 for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    $("#data").append(str[i].Name);
  }
```

Now how to append the 
 to the div which has id (data).It should print

```
Name:Bhavani
Name:Mamata
```

Comment: `$("#data").append(str[i].Name + '<br />');`

Comment: Better yet - wrap each line in `<p></p>` tags instead of forcing line breaks.

Comment: Thank You ..Its working  Arun P Johny

Answer (score 0):

Use details in for loop in place of str.

```
for(i=0;i<details.length;i++)
     {
      $("#data").append("Name : "+details[i].Name+'</br>');

     }
```

**Example :** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahajanankur/80tepb9z/)

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: And i want to use hover on every name...I need those names to be in list and appended to the div tag..can i know how it is possible

Comment: Check this example, http://jsfiddle.net/mahajanankur/80tepb9z/2/
Please accept this answer if you think this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can append each name in a individual paragraph

```
for(i=0;i<details.length;i++) {
       $("#data").append("<li> Name : "+details[i].Name+" </li>");
 }
```

### Output

```
Name : Bhavani 

Name : Mamata
```

### New Edit

Create divs and ul

```
<div id="data">
   <ul id="list_append">

   </ul>
 </div>
```

Now in your JS

```
for(i=0;i<details.length;i++) {
         $("#data").find("#list_append").append("<p> Name : "+details[i].Name+" </p>");

    }
```

this will be appended inside a list

Comment: when im using hover both the names are gtng colored....if i need to be colored only one i need to be keep them in a list and append it to the div tag...so i hw can i make it as a list

Comment: updating my answer see it

Comment: @NagaBhavani check my answer now

Comment: verify my answer so it will be helpful to others too

Comment: I have a question that can we display the details of a person when we click on the name 

Name:Bhavani 

if i click on Bhavani
i hv to get the details of Bhavani like Name,Phone Number,Email ID,and etc

Comment: yes you can by adding a click event on your list items and open a div on that click and hide that div initially make it visible only when user clicks on a particular name

Comment: for(i=0;i<str.length;i++) { $("#data").find("#list_append").append("<li class='choose' id='place"+ str[i].Name+"'>"+"Name : "+str[i].Name+" </li>"); } Iam using like the above...then how can i write click event in jquery

Comment: can anyone say how to do click event for the list for the below code 

for(i=0;i<str.length;i++) 
                    {
                        $("#data").find("#list_append").append("<li class='choose' id='place"+ str[i].Name+"'>"+"Name : "+str[i].Name+" </li>");
                    }

Comment: its better if you try something first yourself and then try to solve if your problem isnt solved, then ask a new question on stack overflow and if you have got an answer for your current question then you should mark it as verified